# SPD pedals too big for cleats?

Tags: spd

I have just purchased some SPD pedals (Shimano PD M8020) and 2 bolt SPD shoes with 2 bolt cleats.

Strangely the cleats fit inside the 'teeth' of the SPD pedals but the teeth of the SPD pedals look like they are too wide and don't engage with the cleats (i.e. the teeth don't need to be pushed apart for the cleat to go in and hence there is no tension holding the cleats to the pedals).

What's happening? Are there different sizes of 2 bolt SPD cleats?

Comment: Can you get a photo of the assembled setup, and also of the cleats specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Ah figured it out, the existing cleats were Crank Brothers cleats (asymmetrical) instead of Shimano SPD  cleats (symmetrical)

Comment: You mean symmetrical/non-symmetrical with respect to the left-right axis? Because SPD cleats are those I would normally call symmetrical, while for Crankbrothers one distinguishes the left one and the right one.